# Login to Sitecore 9.1 across multiple subdomains

Tags: sitecore-api, multisite, identity-server

I am trying to login to Sitecore across multiple domains. I mean, I have two different sites `abc.x.com` and `xyz.x.com`.

is there a way to set the auth cookies at parent domain level, in my case at `x.com` level and let the user to access both the sites?

I noticed few posts for different Sitecore versions, but the one which we are using is 9.1 and i didn't find any article with Sitecore 9.1.

Sitecore 9.1 is using identity server & Owin authentication mechanism, the old posts and articles uses the legacy way of authentication and didn't work.

Any suggestions will help us.

Thanks

Comment: Are you logging in to Sitecore, or using a custom authentication process to log into some protected area of your public website?

Comment: I am trying to login to Sitecore to show some secured content items from Sitecore..

Comment: I am looking for a solution something like this https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1241 in Sitecore 9.1..  Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: Did you try the solution provided in that post?

Comment: Yes I did.. Also i tried overwriting Sitecore.Security.Authentication.FormsAuthenticationProvider but no luck.. I guess Sitecore 9.1 is not using the Forms authentication manager and the architecture changed because they started using the Identity manager.. [not sure].. the request is not even reaching my custom code..

Comment: Update on the above issue, the solution provided in https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1241 might not work, since sitecore 9.1 uses Identity Server.. So any suggestion from anyone.? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore 9.1 uses the **Owin authentication** mechanism, in the earlier versions it uses the .Net legacy form authentication mechanism.
To enable the virtual login the below steps are followed.
**Inherited DefaultCookieAuthenticationOptions** and passed the domain and other required properties in the constructor.

```
    public class CustomCookieAuthenticationOptions : DefaultCookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        public CustomCookieAuthenticationOptions(DefaultCookieAuthenticationProvider provider, ICookieManager cookieManager, AuthenticationTypeResolver authenticationTypeResolver)
            : base(provider, cookieManager, authenticationTypeResolver)
        {
            CookieDomain = ".x.com";
            //Based on your requirement you can set the remaining properties
            //CookieSecure = Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieSecureOption.Never;
        }
    }
}
```

Injected the above class based on the sample given in the [Sitecore document](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/dependency-injection.html) 
Code -

```
public class MyServicesConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<DefaultCookieAuthenticationOptions, CustomCookieAuthenticationOptions>();
        }
    }
```

Config -

```
<configuration>
    <sitecore>
        <services>
            <configurator type= "Test.MyServicesConfigurator, Test.Poc"/>
        </services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

After the above changes, it sets the cookie at x.com but **CORS still failed**. I mean when I login from abc.x.com and try to access the page from the domain xyz.x.com, I am not able to access the Sitecore context set in abc.x.com. [Though both the sites are published from same Sitecore instance].
When further analyzing the issue, looks like the **“ASP.NET_SessionId”** needs to be at parent domain level i.e. x.com level [to share the similar Sitecore session between abc.x.com and xyz.x.com]. So updated the Web.config [Sitecore instance] as below.

```
<system.web>
    …
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" domain=".x.com" />
  </system.web>
```

Now when I **login from abc.x.com**, all the **Sitecore cookies are set at x.com** including the “ASP.NET_SessionId”. So my **Sitecore context built in abc.x.com is accessible in xyz.x.com** and this is what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should review `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.Initialize.CookieAuthentication` pipeline processor.
It uses **Owin authentication** middleware (Cookie in this case). 
So, your goal is to set `CookieDomain` property in `CookieAuthenticationOptions` before `args.App.UseCookieAuthentication` called.
I think, you could do it in 2 ways:

1. Implement your own `CookieAuthentication` pipeline and replace Sitecore's.
2. Try to replace defaut `DefaultCookieAuthenticationOptions` (it's defined as Transient service in `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Infrastructure.ServicesConfigurator`)